# How can I extract rows that does't have a specific value , referring to another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

FIRST TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_MENU
                    (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
                    NAME_MENU VARCHAR(30), 
                    TYPE_OF_MENU VARCHAR(30))

INSERT INTO TABLE_MENU (NAME_MENU, TYPE_OF_MENU) VALUES 
('Menu 1','Dinner'),
('Menu 2','Dinner'),
('Menu 3','Lunch'),
('Menu 4','Dinner'),
('Menu 5','Dinner'),
('Menu 6','Lunch'),
('Menu 7','Lunch'),
('Menu 8','Lunch'),
('Menu 9','Lunch'),
('Menu 10','Lunch');
```

SECOND TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_DISHES 
                    (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                    ID_MENU INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TABLE_MENU(ID),
                    NAME_DISH VARCHAR(30), 
                    TYPE_OF_DISH VARCHAR(30))

INSERT INTO TABLE_DISHES (ID_MENU, NAME_DISH, TYPE_OF_DISH) VALUES 
(1, 'Salad','Vegetable'),
(1, 'Bacon recipes', 'Meat'),
(1, 'Natural Water', 'Drink'),
(2, 'Tomatoes', 'Vegetable'),
(2, 'Barracuda', 'Fish'),
(2, 'White Wine', 'Drink'),
(3, 'Coca Cola', 'Drink'),
(3, 'Beef recipes', 'Meat'),
(4, 'Tuna', 'Fish'),
(4, 'Sparkling Water','Drink'),
(5, 'Carrots', 'Vegetable'),
(5, 'Chicken recipes', 'Meat'),
(6, 'Corn','Vegetable'),
(6, 'Lamb recipes', 'Meat'),
(6, 'Sprite','Drink'),
(7, 'Mix Salad','Vegetable'),
(8, 'Spinach','Vegetable'),
(8, 'Duck recipes', 'Meat'),
(8, 'Fanta', 'Drink'),
(9, 'Jellyfish', 'Fish'),
(10, 'Gammon recipes','Meat'),
(10, 'Beer','Drink');
```

What would be my query if I want to extract from the Table_Menu all the Dinner Menus that HAVE NOT vegetable dishes?

In this case my expected output should be: Menu 3, Menu 4, Menu 9, and Menu 10.

Thank you!

Comment: Sample data and expected results would make things far easier for us the understand the above.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the question

Comment: Which is the expected results and which is the sample? I can't see how you get from either of those tables to the other, Images of data, however, aren't helpful. Take the time to make DDL and DML statments, or *at least* well formatted tabular `text`.

Comment: I edit the question: I hope it's clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for simple NOT EXISTS query.

```sql
SELECT * FROM Table_Manu as om
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM Table_Dishes
WHERE id_menu = om.id_menu
and type_of_dish = 'V')
```

Answer (score 0):

[Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) should work for you.

```
SELECT ID
FROM Type_of_Menu  
EXCEPT  
SELECT ID_menu 
FROM Table_Dishes
WHERE Type_of_Dish = 'V'
```